# LDAP ldapsearch filter: return uidNumber if person has sub ou=mail

Tags: ldap, postfix-mta, openldap, ldap-query, dovecot

I'm trying to construct a ldap filter for my Postfix setup which acts as the example pseudo code below:

```
return uidNumber OF objectClass=posixAccount IF they have a ou=mail AND the mailAddress in this ou=mail IS EQUAL to test@Mydomain.TLD
```

More specific like this while %s holds e.g.: test@Mydomain.TLD:

```
search_base = ou=people,dc=Mydomain,dc=TLD
query_filter = ( &(objectClass=posixAccount)(ou=mail)(mailAddress=%s) )
result_attribute = uidNumber
```

But the rule (ou=mail) does not work and I couldn't figure out how to get it filtering for this ou=mail. My LDAP structure looks like this:

=> dc=MyDomain,dc=TLD
==> ou=People
===> uid=User-1
====> uidNumber=4035
====> ou=mail
=====> mailAddress=test@Mydomain.TLD
===> uid=User-2

## Adding posix User Account

This is how I would add a regular user to the LDAP DB:

```
cat << EOF > ./add_user.ldif
dn:              uid=User-1,ou=people,dc=MyDomain,dc=TLD
objectClass:     top
objectClass:     person
objectClass:     inetOrgPerson
objectClass:     posixAccount
objectClass:     shadowAccount
uidNumber:       2001
gidNumber:       2001
homeDirectory:   /home/User-1
loginShell:      /usr/local/bin/bash
uid:             User-1
userPassword:    TopSecretPassword
displayName:     User-1
givenName:       User-1
mail:            SomeMail@SomeDomain.TLD
telephoneNumber: 0123456
cn:              User-1
sn:              Surname
o:               Some Corporation
jpegPhoto:<      file://Picture.jpg
EOF
```

## Adding ou=mail

Then I would add the User-1's mail container which holds all mail hosting relevant information.

```
cat << EOF > ./add_users_mail_container.ldif
dn: ou=mail,uid=User-1,ou=people,dc=MyDomain,dc=TLD
objectclass: top
objectclass: organizationalUnit
ou: mail
EOF
```

## Adding Mail Accounts

And now I add mail accounts into the ou=mail container. The idea is, that this could be repeated several times with different mailAddress:

```
cat << EOF > /add_users_mail_account.ldif
dn: mailAddress=test@Mydomain.TLD,ou=mail,uid=User-1,ou=people,dc=MyDomain,dc=TLD
objectclass: mailAccount
mailAddress: test@Mydomain.TLD
MailPassword: {SSHA}TopSecretPasswordHash
MailAccountStatus: active
mailStorageDirectory: /home/User-1/mail
#mailAlias: NONE
mailDelivery: dovecot
mailSizeMax: 10240
mailReplyText: Nothing to reply here
mailQuotaSize: 10240
mailQuotaCount: 0
mailservice: smtp
mailservice: pop3
mailservice: imap
mailservice: managesieve
EOF
```

Comment: what other objectclasses do you have on your entry with `posixAccount`? are you sure your mail attribute is `mailAddress` and not `mail`? Is `ou: mail` present on the object you are looking for? Can you add a sample object with `posixAccount` present? Is the `ou=mail` object actually under the user object in the directory?

Comment: I added the requested information in the question above, since a comment won't permit as many characters as I would have required ;)

Let me know if you need any further information. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You cannot do this by a single search filter**. All criteria in search filter only apply to single object.

But in your case 3 objects are involved in your filter:

- an object whose objectClass=posixAccount
- child object whose ou=mail
- grand child object whose mailAddress=test@Mydomain.TLD

**Alternative:**

One alternative is to search for the mailAccount (grand child) object first

```
(&(objectClass=mailAccount)(mailAccount=test@Mydomain.TLD))
```

And then get the search result's parent's parent for the uidNumber.